# Jenkins project order

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Hi I have project flow that I need help with. I have multiple projects that start one global project and then some other projects, the problem is the order if I start more than one project simultaneously. For example I have project a and b and I start them at the same time. What I need to happen.

- a->global->c->d

when finished, then

- b->global->c->d

But what happens actually in my project queue:

- a
- b
- global
- global
- c
- c
- d
- d

So how can I lock whole process and not let project b enter to queue until c finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try those 2 options (or a mix of the 2):

1. Use a wrapping job that triggers the jobs in the required order. For that you can use [Jenkins pipeline (build step)](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) job or [MultiJob](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) or any plugin that enables you to control the jobs order and dependencies.
2. Prevent certain jobs to run in parallel by using [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I have those plugins for other usage. Maybe my question was not clear enough. When I start A then B my queue currently have A then B. But A when finishes it runs Global (On some conditions, not every time) and passes variables from properties file. What I need is B to wait for A to finish and if it should run Global then it runs and only then B. But if A don`t run Global the B is OK.

Comment: In that case, you must use the Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin for preventing job A and B to run at the same time, so only once job A is done, job B will start and this will solve your problem.

Comment: I use Concurrent Builds Plugin but in this specific issue it is not helpful. I will try to clarify more about my question. A triggers C at finish. B triggers C at finish. When I run A and then B my queue is A->B->C->C (Because B does not know when A finished and triggers C). What I need it to be is A->C->B->C. (You can only trigger A & B but not C, C it triggered at the end of A or B)

Comment: So replaces your jobs with 2 new pipeline or MultiJob jobs that the first one (e.g. D) triggers the sequences A+C and the second one (e.g. E) triggers B+C and then prevent D and E to run at the same time using the Concurrent Builds plugin. This will make sure that you'll have your jobs in the order you need: A->C->B->C or B->C->A->C.