# How to pass node parameters in different order in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

We have 5 windows server with tomcat application running. and in Jenkins, we want to remotely stop the tomcat in one order and start the tomcat in different order.

So, we have created 2 different jobs for stop and start respectively and we used Master slave method here.

When i build with parameter, The node parameters are passed in alphabetical order. But i want to pass in different combinations based on the requirement.

Please assist how to pass Node parameters with our choice in jenkins. Thanks

Comment: Actually i dont have issues with Code. I just want to use Stop-Service and Start-Service command.
The issue is I have 5 Slave agents and im passing this Slave agent using "This project is parameterized" option and im running Stop-service command in all slave agent in ascending order. Once this is done, I wanna execute Start-Service command in slave agents in Descending order.
By default jenkins pick slave agents in Alphabetical order. is there anyway i can change it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711849/jenkins-project-order Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? I'm not all too familiar with Jenkins and only stumbled across this question in the quality review queue.